# If true, ignore variable from now on in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, variables, input

I have an assignment which forces me to ignore certain variables if a condition is fullfilled. Basically I'm asking the user for an input and tell him the Valid choices he has, but after a while that originally valid choice is no longer valid anymore. I thought about doing something like this

```
while True:
    choice = input('You can choose between: ', Choice1, Choice2, Choice3)
    if choice == Choice1:
        Choice1Counter +=1
        break
    elif choice == Choice2:
        Choice2Counter +=1
        break
    elif choice == Choice3:
        Choice2Counter +=1
        break
    else:
        choice = input('You can choose between: ', Choice1, Choice2, Choice3)
        continue
```

With this I would first of all 'force' a valid choice and if the input is a valid choice I would add 1 to the Counter of that choice. Should the Counter hit its limit I thought about doing something like this

```
if Choice1Chounter == 4:
    #ignore Choice 1 for the rest of the Programm or until Choice1 is reset
```

This should then basically mean that Choice1 is ignored by the program, which would look a bit like this (in my mind)

`choice = Input('You can choose between: ', Choice1, Choice2, Choice3)`

With that it should basically "print" out the following when running the Program after Choice1Counter hits ist limit

`You can choose between: Choice2 Choice3`

I have 82 Valid Inputs and can't really define all 82! combinations of them, so I thought about this, but can't find a command that just ignores a variable for the rest of the Program.

Comment: use some variable(s) `True/False` to control which choice ignore ie, `ignore = [False, False, True]` and then you can use this to decide which element use.

Comment: BTW: you could use lists `choice[0]`, `choice[1], etc` and `choice_counter[0]`, `choice_counter[1]`, etc. and then you can use `for` loop to do something with this elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be using separate variables for this, but rather a dictionary, and a list of currently valid keys.

```
choices = ["Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3", "Choice4"]
counters = dict((choice, 0) for choice in choices)

while choices:    # exit when no choices left
    choice = raw_input("Choose from %s > " % " ".join(choices))  # input in Py3
    if choice in choices:
        counters[choice] += 1
        if counters[choice] == 4:
            choices.remove(choice)
    else:
       print("That choice is not valid. Try again")
```

Comment: Thanl you very much for your help. I just tried it out and it works perfectly.